# "Unexpected response code: 503" in Chrome. Perhaps having to do with socket.io on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

I am using socket.io with node.js on Heroku.  Everything seems to work.  However, in the Chrome dev bar, I get `Unexpected response code: 503`.  Does anyone know what this could mean?  Should I be concerned about it?  Will it take up memory in the browser?  And if so, can I suppress it?

Comment: You can find the errors code here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes maybe it will help you.

Comment: Are you using websockets ? Because you can't on heroku. More infos here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Heroku "doesn't support" websockets on the Cedar stack yet <s>(no word on when they will)</s> Update: see below.  [They recommend](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku) adding the following code to your Socket.io implementation:

```
// assuming io is the Socket.IO server object
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```

The reason for this is that Heroku adds a routing layer on top of your dynos.  Your code will be executed on *a* server, but it's non-deterministic as to which server it will be.  Thus, WebSockets can't send data to the "correct" server.  Socket.IO will downgrade to long-polling, which keeps the connection alive through the routing layer, ensuring that the events will be executed on the correct server.

UPDATE: [Heroku WebSockets](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/10/8/websockets-public-beta) is now in public beta!  You can add WS support to your app by executing `heroku labs:enable websockets -a myapp` in your app directory.

Comment: I tried using the updated answer.  However, when I do it I still get a 503 error.  I am using a custom domain and have configured the DNS to redirect for the ws://

Comment: Like the answer says, it's still beta.  You'd be better off contacting Heroku support at this point.

Comment: I still haven't figured it out.  Did you get it @SönkeRohde?

Comment: The "UPDATE" worked for me, no code changes required.  However, it took about 30 seconds to become enabled.  Until then, I was still getting the 503.

Comment: The "UPDATE" worked for me as well but I was still getting the 503 error for a bit after enabling websockets on the Heroku app. I also removed my custom domain then restarted the app and then the errors went away(not sure if that was necessary). I then added the custom domain back and restarted the app again and the errors were gone when accessing the via the custom domain as well.

Answer (score 3):

For people coming from google in 2016.

Heroku websockets are now supported, no need to turn them on. [WebSockets on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets)

Make sure to check your logs on Heroku. I noticed the 503 error happen in chrome and after checking logs, turned out that my Heroku app had crashed. There was a bug in my code which caused it to not responding (not socket.io related at all)

Fixed the code and 503 went away!

Comment: What did you do to fix the code ? My node app is on Heroku's cedar-14. I still get the `Unexpected response code: 503` when calling `var ws = new WebSocket('ws://myapp.herokuapp.com');`.

Comment: What exactly is your bug and how did you fix it?