# socket.io:- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, error

Tags: connection, socket.io

My browser console shows the below error while trying to make socket.io connection with web app.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abc.in/socket.io/1/?t=1385867719492. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.abc.in' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
heroku labs:enable websockets -a myapp
```

from [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets)

Alternatively can add:-

```
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```

also look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175051/unexpected-response-code-503-in-chrome-perhaps-having-to-do-with-socket-io-o/15790591#15790591)

Answer (score -1):

Server the client socket.io.js file from the same server where you are trying to connect to.

for example, my initial client code was this and it was throwing error

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect('http://mydomain.com/');
```

once I modified it to this, it worked alright.

```
<script src="http://mydomain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect('http://mydomain.com/');
```

And my server code is,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        next();
    });
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = socketio.listen(server, {log:false, origins:'*:*'});
... //io.connect and events below
```